# How do I add a custom message block at the beginning of the maincontent div in product list/ detail page

Tags: magento2, product

How do I add a custom message block "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet" at the beginning of the "maincontent" div that appear below the breadcrumbs in product list/ detail page.

Comment: If it works for you than give up vote and accept answer to help others as well.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an extra block by override `breadcrumbs.phtml`. Copy `breadcrumbs.phtml` in from `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/breadcrumbs.phtml` to `app/design/frontend/<CompanyNmae.>/<themename>/Magento_Catalog/templates/breadcrumbs.phtml`.  Then call a static block bottom of `breadcrumbs.phtml`.

```
you have to change **static-block-id**


<div class ="static block" style="bottom: 127px; position: absolute;">
<?php   echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('static-block-id')->toHtml();   ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `catalog_product_view.xml` file to your theme under **Magento_Catalog/layout/**

**Create test.phtml file at your theme under Magento_Catalog/product/view/test.phtml**

Than add below code:

```
<referenceContainer name="page.messages">
  <container name="product.info.afterprice" after="breadcrumbs" label="Product info afterprice" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-after-price">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View"
           name="product.info.enquiry" 
           after="breadcrumbs"
           template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/test.phtml">
    </block>
   </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

**Flush cache** and check. Magic will be there !!!

**Update :**

To implement at category page you need to create file `catalog_category_view.xml` at same path as `catalog_product_view.xml` and paste above code.

Comment: Hey @Web Developer this works fine. But the message appears only on product detail page. I need it on product list page too.